# Alternative for InsertTool Or AddTool

Tags: warnings, wxwidgets

I am using wxWidgets 2.9.2, when i use following code

```
//ToolBar
wxToolBar *mainTool = new wxToolBar(this, 120);
wxBitmap newTool(_("images/icons/newtool.png"), wxBITMAP_TYPE_PNG);
wxBitmap saveTool(_("images/icons/savetool.png"), wxBITMAP_TYPE_PNG);
mainTool->InsertTool(0, idToolNew, newTool);
mainTool->InsertTool(1, idToolSave, saveTool);
mainTool->Realize();
SetToolBar(mainTool);
```

i get following warning

> warning C4996: 'wxToolBarBase::InsertTool': was declared deprecated
>   c:\wxwidgets-2.9.2\include\wx\tbarbase.h(546) : see declaration of
>   'wxToolBarBase::InsertTool'

Same happens for AddTool instead of InsertTool

In the tbarbase.h both of them are enclosed in

```
#if WXWIN_COMPATIBILITY_2_8
    // the old versions of the various methods kept for compatibility
    // don't use in the new code!
    // --------------------------------------------------------------
```

But i can't find which function to use as alternative. Do you know the new function i should use instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer for this question on wxWidgets IRC. This is currently a bug in documentation, as it does not suggests the new alternative for `InsertTool`

from chat

> looking in header file it now has a new third argument which is a label

so it should be

`mainTool->InsertTool(1, idToolSave,wxT(""), saveTool);`

This makes the warning vanish.